# Is there a culture that celebrates day of birth, day of conception?

Tags: folklore

Is there any culture that celebrates the day of conception instead of the tipical birthday we enjoy in occidental countries?

It would be a more exact event in some ways, imho.

Comment: that would involve one or both parties to the conception paying *very close attention* to when conception might have happened. If the parties had sex several days in a row around conception time, who knows which one took? Also, who would want to focus on "when my parents had sex"?

Comment: Well I would think not about _when_ my parents had sex. I would rather think ... _when_ I came to world?. ;-)

Comment: that's the problem: conception is about when your parents came. You came to the world 40-odd weeks later.

Comment: I don't know about you, but for me I came to world few hours after my parents came ;-)

Comment: no, dear, your blastocyst assembled a few hours etc. etc. *You* didn't arrive until you exited mum. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have two answer that open a bit the celebration of birth from the day of conception to the day where the pregnancy is planned (a bit earlier) and the first of every year.
Thus I know I'm a bit away from an actual answer but allow an approach.

I came across this story in French while well *socializing* (wasting so much time on social networks). I was glad to find a reference to this in English (had lost the first post in my FB feed).

### [The African birth song](http://aidamanduley.com/2015/03/10/the-real-origin-of-the-african-birth-song/)

The article I first found out was claiming like the following:

> There is a tribe in Africa where the birth date of a child is counted not from when they were born, nor from when they are conceived but from the day that the child was a thought in its mother’s mind.
>
> And when a woman decides that she will have a child, she goes off and sits under a tree, by herself, and she listens until she can hear the song of the child that wants to come. And after she’s heard the song of this child, she comes back to the man who will be the child’s father, and teaches it to him. And then, when they make love to physically conceive the child, some of that time they sing the song of the child, as a way to invite it.
>
> And then, when the mother is pregnant, the mother teaches that child’s song to the midwives and the old women of the village, so that when the child is born, the old women and the people around her sing the child’s song to welcome it. And then, as the child grows up, the other villagers are taught the child’s song.
>
> If the child falls, or hurts its knee, someone picks it up and sings its song to it. Or perhaps the child does something wonderful, or goes through the rites of puberty, then as a way of honoring this person, the people of the village sing his or her song.

This seemed like a really beautiful concept, but I was sad to find out as the linked article claims that this is pure invention, that no tribe seems to do these rituals or anything looking like this (or at least need to prove their existence yet). This [comment](http://aidamanduley.com/2015/03/10/the-real-origin-of-the-african-birth-song/#comment-20272) helps find the origins of this story in the writings of [Jack Kornfiel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_Kornfield), A Path with Heart (Bantam Books, 1993), that seems to be inspired from  an African **FABLE**.

But still, no real proof of this practice before his *testimony*.

### The way Korean count their age

If you are interested in Korean culture, you will probably know about this. The Korean have [another way to count age](http://waegukin.com/korean-age-converter.html).

First on you birthday, you start by already being 1 year old.

Then on each first of January, you stack up one year more, so everyone celebrate the same day.

This gets us to where we can actually get close to an actual answer to your question:

If you were conceived on the first of January, you would celebrate your conceiving every year at a perfect timing. This will still be only for a small portion of people though.

If what you wanted was a way to celebrate a child coming into this world on another date, these answers can match!

Comment: Oh! what two nice traditions (included the african fable). Thank you to bring us these approaches.
I thought there was a culture that lived this tradition of celebrating day of conception. Probably I read that on a fantasy book or something like that. 
I will wait a bit until give you the "correct answer".

Comment: @wadjakman Glad to see that you are not wanting narrow answers exactly about the day of conception